# Dynamically create variables from split string

Tags: python, regex, string, variables, split

What I would like to do is to separate each word of a string and dynamically create variables that I can use independently afterwards, like:

```
String = 'Jurassic Park 3'
Variable1= 'jurassic'
Variable2= 'park'
Variable3= '3'
```

The thing is, the string can be very long. So it has to be able to handle a sentence containing many words.

I already have the beginning of a code:

```
import re
input = str(d["input_text"])

l = []
regex = re.compile(r'(\d+|\s+)')

s = regex.split(input)
l = []
for elem in s: 
    if elem =='':
        continue
    else:
        l.append(elem)

ret_dict = {}
ret_dict["text_list"] = l
ret_dict["returncode"] = 0 # set to 1 to output on the FAILURE output
return ret_dict
```

with that code, at the moment i have this

```
input variable = input_text
output variable = text_list
```

I would like

```
input variable = input_text
output variable1 = variable1
output variable2 = variable2
output variable3 = variable3
output variable4 = variable4
```

etc

Comment: Why don't you want the words in a list (which you already have)?

Comment: At the moment I have only 1 output, and i need to do different things for each word :)

Comment: What does "1.0" mean in your title? Python 1.0 came out in 1994 and Python 2.0 came out in 2000. The latest version of Python is currently 3.6 (though some people are still using 2.7). I would be surprised if you were still using a version of Python that's 20+ years old.

Comment: You can do different things with each word in a list. What would you like to do with them? Perhaps the best approach is not to split up the list, but to use the list correctly. (That is, your question might be an example of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Chris sorry that's what we are using.

Comment: @Metropolis, i would like to check if its a numeric string or not, if it is return 0 and do this, if its not return 1 and do that.

Comment: Update your question with specific information about what you're actually trying to accomplish. Specify what 'do this' and 'do that' actually are.

Comment: @Beginnersinpython, sorry, I just want to make 100% sure. What do you see if you run `python --version` in your terminal?

Comment: @Chris we are using a software, using it self Python, i dont have a Terminal in front of me, but a software. And I asked, we are actually using Python 1.0 :)

Answer (score 1):

When having to define an unknown amount of variables, I like to use Dictionaries. It could be done like this:

```
string = 'Jurassic Park 3'            # Original string
string_list = string.split()          # Returns: ['Jurassic', 'Park', '3']

dic = {}                              
for i in range(len(string_list)):
   var_name = 'Variable{}'.format(i+1)   # Define name of variable, start with 'Variable1'
   dic[var_name] = string_list[i]     # Insert variable name as key and list entry as value
```

Printing the dictionary will return:

```
{'Variable1': 'Jurassic', 'Variable2': 'Park', 'Variable3': '3'}
```

To access e.g. `Variable2`, you could do:

```
dic['Variable2']
```

which returns

```
'Park'
```

If the number of variables become large, I think having them collected in a Dictionary could be easier to handle rather than having the variables defined individually like your question suggests.

If you had e.g. 100 variables but were unsure of the count, it would be easy to check the size of the Dictionary. It would probably be a little harder to keep track of all those variables when they are scattered around and not collected in a bunch.

Comment: Thanks for you answer i tried something else and it does work. I will answer under it

Answer (score 0):

First you can split your string in a list like this

```
string = "Jurassic Park 3"
string_list = string.split()
```

printing this will output:

```
['Jurassic', 'Park', '3']
```

Then we itterate through the list like this

```
for i in range(0, len(string_list)):
    exec("word%d = %s" % (i + 1, repr(string_list[i])));
```

What this does is go through the list of words and puts everything in the variable `word1` `word2` `word3` and however long your string goes on.

Hope this helps

Comment: Don't use exec here, better to use something like a dictionary.

Comment: You are perfectly right, but I was trying to awnser the exact question. The dict solution is better

Answer (score 0):

I found something else, and it does work. I just need to do one more thing on it. if element of the list is 'space', add it to the begginning of the next element.

```
import re
input = str(d["Jurassic Park 3"])

l = []
regex = re.compile(r'(\d+|\s+)')

s = regex.split(input)
l = []
for elem in s: 
    if elem =='':
        continue
    else:
        l.append(elem)

ret_dict = {}
ret_dict["text_list"] = l
ret_dict["returncode"] = 0 # set to 1 to output on the FAILURE output
return ret_dict
```

This does return me :

```
["Jurassic"," ","Park"," ","3"]
```

and i would like to have:

```
["Jurassic"," Park"," 3"]
```